# API Versioning Service in header for Restful

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

all!

I'm check about service of the Version API in Rest Header, I working in Java language and Jersey framework. No URI only header in request all (POST, GET, PUT and DELETE). See a example below.

Example:
GET /Employee
Header - Version: 1.0 <- this it's header that I need implement in version service.

Somebody has tips or pass me the articles and tutorial about it.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what are you trying to do? Are you trying to implement versioning?

Comment: If I want passing value in version header in the restful also receive response in version header.
GET cars?color=blue
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Version: 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Under the Resource Oriented Architectural style for REST you would version the resources themselves and not the service.  You would implement this by use of a custom, versioned media type.  For example, using Java and JAX-RS it might look something like this:

```
@Path("/resource/account/{id}")
@GET
@Produces("application/vnd.mycompany.account-1.0+json")
public Response getAccount(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ...
```

Notice the version number in the media type string in the @Produces annotation.

Then, in your client when you issue the request you use the Accept header to specify that you want the given media type:

```
Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.account-1.0+json
```

In other words, don't do this:

```
@Path("/resource/account/v1/{id}")
```

If you want to support multiple versions your service class might look like this:

```
@Path("/resource/account")
public class AccountWebService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/vnd.mycompany.account-1.0+json")
    public Response getAccount(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ...

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/vnd.mycompany.account-2.0+json")
    public Response getAccountV2(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ...
```

We usually pull the media type out into a public static so we can access and use them from our test clients.  Be sure to use [JerseyTest](http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2013/12/jersey-jerseytest-migration-from-1x-to.html) to test your web services as part of your unit testing.

Comment: I want only header so I pass value into version header and also receive result in version header in the rest. No URI. Example: GET cars?color=blue Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json Version: 1.0

Comment: JAX-RS has a HeaderParam annotation that you use just like PathParam or QueryParam

Comment: One major problem with your approach, though, is that you will have to implement a single method in your service that handles all versions rather than mapping different versions to different methods.

Comment: As Russ said, using this approach you can not have two different methods that have the same path. Resource method selection is not based on @Produces header. Thus you will have to implement this in a single method. Having path as part of the resource URL provides more flexibility in packaging and distribution. You can have different resource classes for difference versions of the same service that might be packaged in the same WAR/EAR of separate WAR/EAR.